# Engagement History Reporting

Tags: reporting, activities, pardot

We use SFDC with Pardot and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to bring all our marketing activity into a reportable format.

I want to see an itemized list of form submissions, landing page visits, and any other interactions with our campaigns. Just like in the lightning component here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6lgkv9tqpzb1y7/Engagement-History-Dashboards-1.png?dl=0

I'd be grateful if you could help me. Maybe it's a custom report type? An API call? We even have CRM Analytics, so I'm sure there is a way to access this info.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_analytics_parent.htm&type=5)?

Comment: of course, that doesn't resolve my issue I'm afraid